# How to display in textbox the item I selected in my listbox containing array "Filelist " (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, listbox

I'm creating VBA UserForm in Excel 2013 wherein the `FileList` array will display all the `.xls` file names from directory in `Listbox1`, upon running the userform whatever I selected/clicked in `Listbox1` should display to a textbox.

How to add that on my code below?

Have tried to add `textbox.Value = ListBox1.Value` did not work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim FileList(), i As Long, x, n As Long, fName As String
    FilePath = "D:\TGSvidasmerger\" 'change to suit
    fName = Dir(FilePath & "*.xls")
    i = 1

    Do While fName <> ""
        ReDim Preserve FileList(1 To i)
        FileList(i) = fName
        i = i + 1
        fName = Dir()
    Loop

    ReDim Preserve FileList(1 To i - 1)

    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear
        .List = FileList
    End With

    textbox.Value = ListBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a *"This is my code please finish my project question"* if you don't show what you have tried to solve your issue. • So where exactly did you get stuck? Any errors? Why couldn't you solve it? • Have you tried the `ListBox_Click` event?

Comment: The code is working except the textbox.Value = ListBox1.Value, it doesn't show any error.. its just doesn't work. whatever I select in list items should show on textbox..

Comment: Because `UserForm_Initialize` runs just once when the form loads. But you need to update your TextBox whenever someone clicks on the ListBox. Therefore you need the `ListBox_Click` event, so I ask again: Have you tried it? • Also as you can imagine *"did not work"* is the worst error description you can give because it tells nothing about *what* went wrong.